# Install multiple operating systems on smartphones?

Tags: mobile, operating-system

I was wondering if it is possible to configure mobile phones to support multiple Operating Systems *for development*.

Not talking about running virtual machines on the phone, but to actually install multiple OS's on the same mobile phone giving a boot option when switching on the phone. This would be a great help to developers test real devices.

Need someone to put some light on this. Planning to write a paper on this if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, why not?.

For example, i tested this

[idroid](http://www.idroidproject.org/)  running android and iphone os in a single device.

And there are another alternatives

[webos & android](http://www.redmondpie.com/cyanogenmod-7-for-touchpad-makes-further-progress-touchscreen-wi-fi-sound-and-accelerometer-now-working-video/)

But exists many problems:

a) officially (Apple, Microsoft and Google) they don't want that. So i don't think that they will do it officially.

b) since it is not official then it will lack drivers.  For example, iDroid lack several drivers

Comment: there are many companies in the world (like Samsung here in India) who have their own OS (called BADA here). that company though, provides with mobile phones with both android and BADA OS. BADA is not an impressive platform, lacks many features. so, for companies like these, if it was possible to provide devices running both BADA and android systems, would be a big boost to their sales. some platforms are just meant for linux developers, and BADA is one of them. and wonder if both the OS could share the same SD card. A developer may develop the app for one platform and test it on both of them.

Comment: the problem of lacking drivers would also get solved if the same company provides with multiple OS. and even if companies don't have multiple OS, at least if the device is compatible to do so, consumers are free to install the OS of their choice. Don't know if that makes sense, but can really boost up the market of these platform-free devices.